# ThreeJs Editor: Why is the translate position arrow not centered on the model I import

Tags: three.js

I have been trying to learn ThreeJs for a while, but I noticed that anytime I import a model into the Three.js editor I would be able to see the translate arrow, but the model would be far above it. I have tried scaling it down but this is not best way to go. What is the cause of this ? as I need to scale down the OBJ  or zoom out my camera to see it well.

[image]

Comment: The offset is probably part of your model. In the modeling tool you can get rid of it with options like "Freeze Transformations" (Maya) or "Apply Object Position / Scale" (Blender).

Comment: You can also do this on the three.js side, though having your model's geometry corrected before importing _is_ the better way. After you import your OBJ, center all of its geometry: `returnedObj.children.forEach(function(node){ node.geometry.center(); });`. That will center the geometry at its geometric center, which is what you're looking for.